# Finding bug in FMX TabControl style

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to track down a problem with the Jet style on Tab Control whereby when the tab is selected it goes white and the Icon disappears. The problem is only in the 10.2 Tokyo under iOS.

How are events like "down" or "selected" handled in an FMX style? 
If I open the style designer I can see the style for a "tabitemcustom". I can see how the tab is put together but I cant see how its defined in its alternative state.

Comment: Perhaps this hint leads you forward: In Berlin `FMX.TabControl.TTabControl.SetTabIndex()` is a comment: `// When user change active tab (iOS), we need close all active pickers`. Did not look further as I can't trace it in the debugger.

Comment: The states you describe are defined in BitmapLinks (or link states; sorry, I am not on my PC right now so can't check the exact term). Basically, you have a big image file with all the images that define your style and you use regions to define what is shown according to the state of the tab or when the mouse hovers. You will see rectangles of different colors for thsi

Comment: The same problem I have. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: No, I went back to Berlin as this appears to be one of the many bugs in Tokyo. There is a hotfix for Tokyo that has just been released. I have not had a chance to test and see if this is resolved.

Comment: I have the hotfix 1 for Tokyo and the same problem.